# Why data isnt getting saved in cookies in laravel?

Tags: laravel

This is my code,

```
namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use Illuminate\Http\Response;
use App\Http\Requests;
use App\Http\Controllers\Controller;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Cookie;

...

$inquiryArr = [
   'productId' => $request->pId,
   'qtySelected' => $request->qSel,
   'sizeId' => $request->classVal
];

$response = new Response('1');
$response->withCookie(cookie()->forever('inquiryArr', serialize($inquiryArr)));
```

I want the array to get saved in cookies, there isnt any error but the cookies arent getting added.

Data isnt getting saved, Please Help

Comment: Do you `return` the response?

Comment: no, but return where?

Comment: ohh thanks i got it